# Class Block Instance Variable

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

Without too much judgement as to the design of this code, I am wondering how to work around the retain cycle I've created...

```
@interface BlockClass : NSObject
{
    id actualObject;
    NSError *actualError;
    void (^block)(id, NSError *);
}
@end

@implementation BlockClass

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        block = ^(id object, NSError *error){
            actualObject = object; // Compiler warns: capturing 'self' strongly in this block is likely lead to a retain cycle
            actualError  = error;
        };
    }

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're retaining the block by assigning it to an ivar, and since the block assigns to an ivar, it needs to retain self--hence the retain cycle.

You could have equivalent behavior by returning the block from an instance method:

```
@interface BlockClass : NSObject
{
    id actualObject;
    NSError *actualError;
}
@end

@implementation BlockClass

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
    }

    return self;
}

-(void (^)(id, NSError *))block {
    return ^(id object, NSError *error){
        actualObject = object;
        actualError  = error;
    };
}

@end
```

This avoids the retain cycle because the block returned is released as soon as it's executed.

Comment: Yep. This definitely all makes sense. Thank you.